# SQL Bigquery Counting repeated customers from transaction table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a transaction table that looks something like this.

| userid | orderDate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2021-11-01 | 20 |
| 112 | 2021-09-07 | 17 |
| 111 | 2021-11-21 | 17 |

I want to count how many distinct customers (userid) that bought from our store this month also bought from our store in the previous month. For example, in February 2020, we had 20 customers and out of these 20 customers 7 of them also bought from our store in the previous month, January 2020. I want to do this for all the previous months so ending up with something like.

| year | month | repeated customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 01 | 11 |
| 2020 | 02 | 7 |
| 2020 | 03 | 9 |

I have written this but this only works for only the current month. How would I iterate or rewrite it to get the table as shown above.

```
WITH CURRENT_PERIOD AS (
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(orderDate) BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
),

PREVIOUS_PERIOD AS (
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(orderDate) BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),MONTH) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
)

SELECT count(1)
FROM CURRENT_PERIOD RC
WHERE RC.userid IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM PREVIOUS_PERIOD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can summarize to get one record per month, use `lag()`, and then aggregate:

```
select yyyymm,
       countif(prev_yyyymm = date_add(yyyymm, interval -1 month)
from (select userid, date_trunc(order_date, month) as yyyymm,
             lag(date_trunc(order_date, month)) over (partition by userid order by date_trunc(order_date, month)) as prev_yyyymm
      from table1
      group by 1, 2
     ) t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```